# Geopandas defaulting to world map despite only using US data and shape file

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I've been trying to map the route of US domestic flights over a map of the United States through Geopandas. I can map my shapefile of flights without any problem, but when I try to add another layer showing the United States underneath, the resulting plot is the size of Geopandas' world map, but only shows the US and flights geometries.

```
import matplotlib as mp
import geopandas as gp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyproj as pj
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import descartes
flights = gp.read_file(r"C:\Users\corne\git\flight\flights.shp")
usmap = gp.read_file(r"C:\Users\corne\git\flight\Igismap\UnitedStates_Boundary.shp")
usmap = usmap.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,6))
flights.plot(ax=ax)
usmap.plot(ax = ax)
```

Here is the resulting map 
[US-only data being plotted on World map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAYwu.png)

Comment: Did you try `geoplot.polyplot(usmap, ax = ax)` from `geoplot` ? Sometimes it respects more the limits of the first layer

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what the problem is? Do you just want the plot to be smaller?

Comment: I want to be able to set a bounding box that will center over my shapefile (which is just the US, not the entire world)

Comment: linog2, it looks like geoplot is not installed. When I try installing it with pip install, rasterio fails to install because of some issue with gdal. The error message points to a Readme file that is not in my gdal files...

Comment: Looks like the issue was that the shape file included minor outlying islands in the Pacific...

Answer (score 0):

1. I cant see any base map in your piece of code.
2. In javascript I use .shp .dbf .prj and Compiled shape all  4 files together. You would find all 4 files in the compressed form when you downloaded .shp from igismap.